# XPath Parser java redundancy

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

So I need to parse an XML file with XPath.
All works well but if i have a tag which is present more than one time, my code displays all the subtags of all the same tags inside a tag.
For example: i have a

```
<a>
  <b></b>
</a>
<c></c>
<a>
  <b></b>
</a>
```

the output will be :

```
a
 b
 b
c
a
 b
 b
```

my code is this :

```
 public void parseFileXPath() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, XPathExpressionException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(file);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();

    String expression;
    Node node;
    NodeList nodeList;

    expression="/*";
    node = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression,doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
    //System.out.println(node.getNodeName());

    expression="/frogans-fsdl/*";
    nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression,doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);


    NodeList nodeList1;


    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        String aTag = nodeList.item(i).getNodeName();

        System.out.println(aTag);
        expression="/frogans-fsdl/"+aTag+"/*";
        nodeList1 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression,doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for (int j = 0; j < nodeList1.getLength(); j++) {

            System.out.println("\t"+nodeList1.item(j).getNodeName());
            //TODO
            //Display what's inside each tag
        }

        expression="";
    }



}
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following inner loop code might help what the output you want:

```
    NodeList nodeList1;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getNodeName());
        expression="*";
        nodeList1 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression,nodeList.item(i),XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int j = 0; j < nodeList1.getLength(); j++) {
            System.out.println("\t"+nodeList1.item(j).getNodeName());
        }
    }
```

Basically you need to pass the nodeList.item(i) as second argument on the subsequent xpath evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Your first xath finds all children of frogans-fsdl. Which probably `a,c,a`
With your second xpaht `/frogans-fsdl/a/*"` you are looking in the whol document for all children of /frogans-fsdl/a/,/frogans-fsdl/c/ and /frogans-fsdl/a/ again.

You should change your second xpaht to `*` and use the nodeList.item(i) as context node for your second evaluate call.

Comment: yep, i got it from the response of Mahesh, i was so dumb i wasn't thinking i was re-parsing the whole file.